# Why does managing OpenGl in Rust require Unsafe Code?

Tags: opengl, rust

I've been writing an app in Rust that uses some OpenGL, and I've observed a trend in how OpenGl is accessed/managed in rust code. Frequently it seems that managing or creating an OpenGl context requires `unsafe`.

Why do these examples require unsafe code? I haven't been running into any problems because of this unsafe designator, but I'm just curious as to why its there. What kind of problems or constraints do these unsafe requirements impose on developers?

from glutins [Multi-Window example](https://github.com/rust-windowing/glutin/blob/master/glutin_examples/examples/multiwindow.rs)

```rust
    //...
    let mut windows = std::collections::HashMap::new();
    for index in 0..3 {
        let title = format!("Charming Window #{}", index + 1);
        let wb = WindowBuilder::new().with_title(title);
        let windowed_context = ContextBuilder::new().build_windowed(wb, &el).unwrap();
        //uses unsafe code
        let windowed_context = unsafe { windowed_context.make_current().unwrap() };
        let gl = support::load(&windowed_context.context());
        let window_id = windowed_context.window().id();
        let context_id = ct.insert(ContextCurrentWrapper::PossiblyCurrent(
            ContextWrapper::Windowed(windowed_context),
        ));
        windows.insert(window_id, (context_id, gl, index));
    }
    //...
```

from [fltk-rs glow demo](https://github.com/MoAlyousef/fltk-rs-demos/blob/master/glow/src/main.rs)

```rust
   //...
    unsafe {
        let gl = glow::Context::from_loader_function(|s| {
            win.get_proc_address(s) as *const _
        });

        let vertex_array = gl
            .create_vertex_array()
            .expect("Cannot create vertex array");
        gl.bind_vertex_array(Some(vertex_array));

        let program = gl.create_program().expect("Cannot create program");
        //...
        win.draw(move |w| {
            gl.clear(glow::COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            gl.draw_arrays(glow::TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
            w.swap_buffers();
        });
    }
     //...
```

Comment: Its not 100% clear to me why [`make_current()`](https://docs.rs/glutin/0.26.0/glutin/struct.ContextWrapper.html#method.make_current) is `unsafe`, the documentation doesn't make it clear to me whether its due to multi-threaded reasons or from it being in an indeterminate state if it should fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL is implemented as a library with a C ABI. If you want to call a C function from rust, it always means you [have to use `unsafe`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#using-extern-functions-to-call-external-code) because the C implementation knows nothing about the safety features of rust and naturally doesn't support them. Furthermore, OpenGL uses raw pointers in its API to pass data from or to the GL, which also requires `unsafe` code in rust.